# Polycyclic nitrogen network?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polymers, allotropes

[image: structure]

So today I suddenly stricken with this structure and started to wonder if this polymeric structure of nitrogen is possible or not? If possible then what's its stability?

Comment: With N, it will collapse instantly. With P, it might stand a chance.

Comment: It's not "graphene-with-nitrogen" exactly, but I see what you mean. It's a planar tiling (like graphene) but with mixed 12-ring/3-rings as opposed to a hexagonal tiling

Comment: you could also go with squares/octagons like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1-uniform_n2.svg (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons) - although as other commenters point out, these are extremely chemically unlikely! (it's this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1-uniform_n4.svg)

Comment: Yikes!  Where was this dreamed up?

Comment: Looks like someone tried out his chemicals sketching software. ? Polmeric nitrogen exists (at very high pressures), but the structure is quite different. https://phys.org/news/2004-08-polymeric-nitrogen-synthesised.html

Comment: What do you mean by "possible" and "stable"?

Comment: That would make quite a BOOM as it collapsed...

Comment: @Ivan Ah? Why so? O:)

Comment: After reading your comments and a bit of googling I found this : This polymeric structure of nitrogen isn't possible but cg-n structure at very high pressure (100 GPa) is possible. This structure is highly unstable and upon release in open atmosphere it would be highly exothermic.

Comment: @Mithoron By possible I meant that can this structure be formed anywhere in the universe without decomposing to another structure and by stable I meant that is it stable at STP?

Answer (score 8):

I searched [CCDC](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/) for the infinite structures with the following building block:

[image]

where where each vertex contains *any* non-metal atom linked by *any* type of bond. The only known crystal structure that would meet these criteria is $\ce{[B12]2[CBC][C2]Mg_{1.42}}$ where $\ce{B12}$ icosahedra are linked *via* $\ce{B–C}$ and $\ce{B–B}$ bonds forming the moieties of the previously shown topology:

> [image]
>   **Figure 2**. Projection of the $\ce{B25C4Mg_{1.42}}$ structure onto the $0ac$ plane (the block of icosahedra of boron carbide structure is marked by shading).

Unfortunately, no similar structures are found for nitrogen yet. Also, the structural motif breaks on boron clusters, but this is the closest as I was able to get.

#### Reference

1. Ponomarev, V. I.; Konovalikhin, S. V.; Kovalev, I. D.; Vershinnikov, V. I.; Borovinskaya, I. P. *Mendeleev Communications* **2014,** *24* (1), 15–16. [DOI: 10.1016/j.mencom.2013.12.004](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mencom.2013.12.004).

Comment: After a bit of research i found http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927025614008209, but ccdc structure of nitrogen isn't possible/found yet

Comment: @G.OVed Ah, the mighty USPEX – this program predicted numerous structures at extreme conditions. Actually, you can answer your own question with this, I think the article is relevant.