# Possibility of non-hexagonal graphene

Tags: crystal-structure, carbon-allotropes

I understand that monolayer carbon naturally forms in a regular hexagonal tiling.
Is it, however, possible (if difficult) to form carbon monolayers of a different structure?

A 3-12-12 tiling, for example…

[image: Semiregular Tiling 3-12-12 (Truncated Hexagonal) by R. A. Nonenmacher. This file is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International, 3.0 Unported, 2.5 Generic, 2.0 Generic and 1.0 Generic license.]

(with carbon atoms at the vertices and bonds along the edges) would allow two single bonds and one double bond per atom, just like in normal graphene.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Could you use an image that shows the arrangement of atoms? It is not clear what  your graphic represents.

Comment: I remember answering a similar question an year or so ago: [Is this structure stable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87684/is-this-structure-stable-with-image) — the same pattern, but with nitrogen atoms. Probably might be interesting for you (also check out the comments to that question).

Comment: @andselisk USPEX sounds interesting. I should try and look into that.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penta-graphene https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phagraphene